# apply CSS to links inside DIV

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to display a headband with some links. 
Following code for my CSS file :

```
.headband{
    width:100%;
    height:15%;
    background-color:#00CCFF;
    font-family:"Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    color:#999;
}

.head-profile {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
}

.head-proposition {
    position:relative;
    float:right;
}
```

But even with some tries, it's not applicable to my links.. (or when it is, the design page breaks) .

EDIT : In fact, in my HTML, my links don't take the color parameter :

```
<div class="headband">
    <div class="head-profile">
LOGGED AS <a href="index.php?page=profil&profil=<?echo $_SESSION['profil']?>"><b><u><?echo $_SESSION['profil']?></u></b></a><br/>
  <a href="index.php?page=logout">
    </div>

    <div class="head-proposition">
    <a href="index.php?page=proposition&query=<?echo $query?>">
     POST AN EVENT</a> </div>
</div>
```

How to say in CSS that the 'headband' style must be applied to links inside 'headband' class ?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: Need to see the HTML which these styles are trying to target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a look at [Combinators in CSS](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp).
If you want the exact style of `.headband` to apply for `<a>` elements inside `.headband` too, then use

```
.headband, .headband a {
    /* ... */
}
```

Otherwise, just create a new section like

```
.headband a {
    /* ... */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write the following:

```
.headband a{
    //your style
}
```

Then the style will be applied to all anchor objects inside an object of the class "headband".

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
.headband{
    width:100%;
    height:15%;
    background-color:#00CCFF;
    font-family:"Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
    color:#999;
}

.headband a {
   display:block;
   // YOUR CODE HERE
}
```